# Python I2C communication TTP229

Tags: python, linux, arduino, raspberry-pi, i2c

I need to read 2 different bytes from TTP229 (16 keys or 8 keys touch pad detector).
I use I2C In Python. [TTP229 datasheet PDF](http://www.robotpark.com/image/data/PRO/91409/TTP229.pdf).
I can't read the second byte, but I can get the first byte.

Python code:

```
import smbus
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
adressTTP229 =  0x57 #0xAF>>1
byte1 = bus.read_byte(adressTTP229)
byte2 = bus.read_byte(adressTTP229)
```

`byte1` is always equal to `byte2`.

This Arduino code, works ok:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#define ttp229 (0xAF>>1) 

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);  // start serial for output
  Wire.begin();
}

void loop() {
  delay(50);
  bool isNewData = false;
  Wire.requestFrom(ttp229,2,true);
  while (Wire.available()) { 
    uint16_t b1 = Wire.read(); // receive a first byte
    uint16_t b2 = Wire.read(); // receive a second byte
    if (b1==b2 && b2==0) {break;}
    //... 

    }
  }
```

How do I use Arduino's `requestFrom()` function in Python?

Comment: Written module in C for use in Python, to work with the chip TTP229.
[github libttp229](https://github.com/Skaper/libttp229)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
import smbus, time
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
while True:
   print bus.read_word(0xAF)
   time.sleep(0.1)
```

dont change address, bus doe the conversion, and if you read byte you will always get the same first byte. you want to read a word = 2 bytes at once

not tested, but might work, have it ordered and will test